# Text overflow ellipsis with several spans

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing three `span` elements inside. The three `span` elements form a single text, which I want to be limited to a single line. I would like to apply ellipsis to the text if its width is larger than the `div`'s

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g56rffds/)

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <span>First text</span>
  <span>Second text</span>
  <span>Third long, long text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want?

```
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g56rffds/1/